# Error when using simple_dom_html get title page?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://api.nrelate.com/mpw_wp/0.51.4/?tag=nrelate_popular&domain=dongcam.vn&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdongcam.vn%2Ft10041&maxageposts=4320&nr_div_number=2&increment=1';
$html = file_get_html($url);
// find all span tags with class=nr_post_title
foreach($html->find('span.nr_post_title') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

=> Error can't get title with `<span class=\"nr_post_title\">` , How to fix it ?

Comment: maybe the nRelate.sw part the beginning might be messing things up?  can you try with something basic like the example here, which uses google.com?  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The URL seems to return HTML wrapped in JavaScript. Why are you using PHP Simple Dom to parse JavaScript?

Comment: @SalmanA: I want get a few row data !

Comment: Does the API publish the data in any alternate format (JSON, JSPNP, XML, etc)?

Comment: The output is not even html why you are treating it as html?